# Implementing long-polling in server

Tags: java, javascript, restlet, long-polling

i'm trying to develop a long-polling on my javascript client and in my server that management the http requests.
In server i have a restlet listening the request and processing them, in the client i have a javascript api that make http calls with xmlhttprequest object.

Now i have in js a setTimeOut with a delay of 3 seconds that makes polling to the server, in most request i receive nothing, i want to implement a long-polling. 
My question is if i have to implement in my server the logic of long-polling, my reslet uses jetty, and i would to implement something like 'Thread.sleep' until i have any to send to client? or i have natively methods in java or restlet that allow me to do without long implementation.

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: you could increase your delay e.g. by a `2` factor everytime your response is empty (so the delay would become 3/6/12/24/48/96/... seconds) and then set it again to 3 seconds when you receive something

Comment: But, in this case, when i do the 5º pull and is empty, the next pull will be in 96 seconds?.... very long time, therefore i want to replace for long polling

Comment: If you are open to new technologies: Take a look at http://socket.io/. The serverside is node.js. And it uses websockets, which are even better then longpolling and has several fallbacks if websockets are not available.

Comment: websockets is a good solution, but cant change at this moment my java/restlet server for nodejs, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i have implemented the long polling using the java concurrency: wait() & notify() system for java objects.